# Redis Monitor mode with authentication

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redislabs

Redis monitor cmd is not working with authentication:

Cmd: `redis-cli -h <redis_endpoint> -p <port> -n <database> -a <password> monitor`

error: `(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'MONITOR' command`

But the same works with Redis without authentication:
`redis-cli -h <redis_endpoint> -p 6379 monitor`

Can someone help with correct redis-cli monitor cmd that works with database and password.

Comment: you can't monitor a single database in redis, you monitor it as a whole. what happens when you remove the -n <database> option ?

Comment: ```redis-cli -h <redis_endpoint> -p <port> -a <password> monitor``` with this getting (error) NOAUTH Authentication required

Comment: do you have a `$` sign in your password ? or any other special charachter space etc ?

Comment: no, doesn't have any special character in the password( only alphanumeric).